# Pattern image setting in android studio show black tile in between?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

[image]

This is screenshot when i was trying to set gradient in android studio
here is my code for set backgourd image as pattern -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_bg_pattern"
        android:tileMode="mirror" />
```

and i applied this XML file into the activity_main.xml file

```
android:background="@layout/backrepeat"
```

**Note:-** the image i was added from image asset.(but when i copy and directly paste it was working fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Abhishek answer is also correct but this is problem occurs when we try to use a patter image with some low pixels means 50x50Px so the image is not android draw the small image as tile format so we see clearly the black space if we use some big image like above 150*150px then it create the good texture that you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

In My Case this works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/single_img"
    android:tileModeX="repeat"
    android:tileModeY="repeat"
    />
```